# A question about Normal subgroups of $S_4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H=\{e,(1,2),(3,4)\}$ and $K=\{e,(1,2),(3,4),(1,3),(2,4),(1,4),(2,3)\}$ be subgroups of $S_4$  where $e$ is the identity in  $S_4$. Then is/are normal subgroups of $S_4$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde $K$ is different between that question and this one. However, [How to show that $K≤S_4$ is a normal subgroup?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312071/how-to-show-that-k-leq-s-4-is-a-normal-subgroup?rq=1) adresses this one specifically, in a way that makes me think it's a typo.

Comment: Neither of those is normal and that's easy to see. But I think both of them are if you correct the possible typos...